# W3C CSS Validator not detecting correct syntax like WebStorm

Tags: html, css, validation

I would like to **check** my **page** for **CSS errors**. But it behaves like my WebStorm that is showing nearly the same mistakes like the W3C CSS Validator does.

Take this **[validation](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http%3A%2F%2Farda-maps.org%2F&profile=css3&warning=no&lang=de&vextwarning=true)** with its over 100 errors. There you can see that even ***fill*** is marked as error. But this is totally allowed and working in all browsers. So why or how can I filter out those properties so that I can really see errors that are actually errors?

Comment: Well overall I'm interested in those things because as I said WebStorm also behaves in this way. And I'm someone that would like to see while writing statements if they are correct. So Maybe the question could also be how to say WebStorn that *fill* is a correct property.

Comment: HTML validator is still relevant (it was patched from validator.nu a few years ago) but CSS validator, even though it was improved too for vendor prefix (not being) "errors" is... well let's say it's very conservative. CSS3 isn't SVG and it has 20+ modules in various states of consensus and implementation (WDraft, LC, PR, CR, REC) and I guess W3C hasn't that much time and money for improving this validator often.

Comment: Also, your website can't decide if it's HTML4, HTML5 or XHTML. My advice, choose one standard and stick with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is a usual behaviour of Webstorm in terms of SVG properties.